# How can I use Problems panel in my vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use Problems panel in my vscode extension,but I can not find the api.How can I use it or where can I find the api about Problems panel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is achieved through the use of Diagnostic objects.  Each object will be a separate entry in the Problems panel.

Take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server#_adding-a-simple-validation for an example of how it's done.

If you are not writing a language server, then you need to look into the [DiagnosticsCollection class](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DiagnosticCollection).